# Gdrive cli upload to a certain folder

Tags: linux, command-line, google-drive

Using gdrive cli - can I upload to a certain folder in my drive? I can upload a whole folder, or files, or tree of folder and file, but wasn't able to find a way to upload to an already created folder.

Comment: gdrive is not working anymore since "Logging in with google for this application has temporarily been disabled"

Answer (score 10):

From https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive

Make directory

```
$ gdrive mkdir gdrive-bin
Directory 0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk created
```

Upload file to directory

```
$ gdrive upload --parent 0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk gdrive-osx-x64
Uploading gdrive-osx-x64
Uploaded 0B3X9GlR6EmbnNTk0SkV0bm5Hd0E at 2.5 MB/s, total 8.3 MB
```

Comment: `gdrive upload --parent 0B3X9GlR6EmbnY1RLVTk5VUtOVkk --recursive path/of/folder` to upload directory